# linked list program is not functioning properly

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, append, singly-linked-list

The given program is not showing all the elements of the linked list.
I am having problem in identifying the error.

At first I initialized the head with a null value then made a temporary variable and assigned it an integer value and pointer to the next node.
Then I made an another node named temp1 and linked it with the head.
It will only be linked when "i" will be equal to 1.

Then equated temp1 to the next node and did the same.

//Linked list
//Inserting the nodes.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
    int n;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *head;

int main ()
{
    int i, s, x, y;
    i = 0;
    struct node *temp;
    struct node *temp1;
    struct node *cur;
    head = NULL;
    scanf ("%d", &s);     //No. of nodes.
    while (i < s)
    {
        scanf ("%d", &x);
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            temp = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
            temp->n = x;
            temp->next = NULL;
            head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
            temp->n = x;
            temp->next = NULL;
            temp1 = temp;
            if (i == 1)
            {
                head->next = temp1;
            }
            temp1 = temp1->next;  //Assigning the next node.i.e. NULL value
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    cur = head;
    while (cur != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%d", cur->n);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but don't cast the return value of `malloc` and prefer `ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr))` to repeating the type.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but the y variable is never used

Comment: I'm not clear what you are using temp1 for since its value is never used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you have to include the header `<stdlib.h>`.

The problem is in this statement

```
temp1 = temp;
```

if `i` is not equal to `1` then after this statement

```
temp1 = temp1->next;
```

`temp1` becomes equal to `NULL`.

So all other nodes are not added to the list because there is a cycling

```
temp1 = temp;
//...
temp1 = temp1->next;
```

Change the loop the following way

```
  while (i < s)
    {
      scanf ("%d", &x);
      if (head == NULL)
    {
      temp = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
      temp->n = x;
      temp->next = NULL;
      head = temp;
      temp1 = head;
    }
      else
    {
      temp = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
      temp->n = x;
      temp->next = NULL;
      temp1->next = temp;
      temp1 = temp;
    }
    i++;
    }
```

Pay attention to that you should declare variables in a block scope where they are used. Otherwise the program will be unreadable.

The approach you are using can be called as an Java approach.

In C the program can look much simpler. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
  int n;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *head;

int main( void )
{
    struct node **temp = &head;

    size_t n = 0;

    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        *temp = (struct node *) malloc ( sizeof ( struct node ) );

        int value = 0;

        scanf ( "%d", &value);

        ( *temp )->n = value;
        ( *temp )->next = NULL;

        temp = &( *temp )->next;
    }

    for ( struct node *cur = head; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next )
    {
        printf ("%d -> ", cur->n );
    }
    puts( "NULL" );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following changed section

```
    {
      temp = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
      temp->n = x;
      temp->next = NULL;
      head = temp;
      temp1 = head;
    }
      else
    {
      temp = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
      temp->n = x;
      temp->next = NULL;
      temp1->next = temp;
      temp1 = temp1->next;  //Assigning the next node.i.e. NULL value
    }
```

Instead of relying on

```
   if (i == 1) {
      head->next = temp1;
   }
```

I assign `head` on `temp1` while creating the head, which is meant to be happen only first time.

There were also some linkage issues in your `else` portion.

Answer (score 1):

You lose nodes beyond the first two, since you never link them to the list. Use meaningful names for variables: rename `temp1` to `tail` and initialize it to `NULL` in the beginning. Then the loop body becomes:

```
if (scanf(" %d", &x) != 1) {
    // FIXME: handle error
}
temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
temp->n = x;
temp->next = NULL;
if (tail == NULL) {
    head = temp;
} else {
    tail->next = temp;
}
tail = temp;
++i;
```

(Untested.)

Rationale: You want to add new nodes to the end (tail) of the list. The easiest way is to keep track of the tail in an appropriately-named variable, and simply link every node to `tail->next` instead of convoluted logic like checking for the node count, etc. The only special case is the empty list, i.e., both `head` and `tail` are `NULL`, and the difference is just one line, so don't duplicate the whole block of code to set up the new node.

Comment: I would also revisit the names (and existence) of other variables, i.e., `s` is `total_nodes`, `x` could be `n` to match the field of `struct node` (although you could consider renaming that `n` to something like `value`?), `i` is `node_count`, and `y` is unnecessary and can be deleted. `temp` could also be called `node`. I find it helpful to first come up with a descriptive name for a variable, and if I can't there's probably something else I need to figure out first – adding something like `temp1` is a good example of a sign to step back and rethink what you are doing. =)